# Tensorflow Object Detection API - PYTHONPATH unsets itself, when using different terminal

Tags: tensorflow, testing, installation, module, object-detection

This might be a silly question, but I didn't find anything on the internet. I am trying to run the object_detection API of tensorflow in Windows 10. I've installed all the packages correctly and I've also added the "**models**" directory to the PYTHONPATH, using **windows cmd**:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\Tensorflow\models
```

And I also verify that the PYTHONPATH is set correctly, by typing **set PYTHONPATH**, which gives me this output:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files\Tensorflow\models
```

Running the following test

```
python research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

I get the output:

```
Ran 20 tests in 37.331s
OK (Skipped 1)
```

Which is great. However, If I open another terminal and type

```
python research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named official`

However, If i type **set PYTHONPATH** command to verify that the PYTHONPATH is correct I get:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Kohli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\Tensorflow\models;C:\Users\Kohli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\Tensorflow\models\official;C:\Users\Kohli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\Tensorflow\models\research
```

which is different from the previous terminal output. Moreover, when I open the "Enviroment Variables" tab, I can see that PYTHONPATH exists.

If I add the models directory to PYTHONPATH once again, It will work, but Only for that particular terminal. However, I don't understand why this is happening. Does the "set PYTHONPATH" command creates a virtual environment for that particular terminal or something? How can i permanently add models dir to PYTHONPATH, without typing **set PYTHONPATH** or **os.path.append('path/to/models')** ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. An environment variable is set only in the current terminal instance.

Comment: So, how can I permanently add models dir to pythonpath?

Comment: you can store the models/research, models path in ~/.bashrc file for permanently in ubuntu. For windows try add path in environmental variables by edit properties on C disk